# PowerShell to get any Custom lists and Libraries in a site

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, pnp

Looking to obtain a list of any generic lists or libraries that have been created by users in a Site (exclude any OOTB, hidden or system lists.)  have tried filtering on various list properties via PowerShell, was wondering if any one can comment.  thanks

Answer (score 0):

Mark, BaseTemplate and BaseType is your friend. Microsoft now embraces the use of PnP.PowerShell, although it's troublesome because you need to ask your Global Admin to allow you run this script.

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url "{your-site-url}" -DeviceLogin
#below is for generic custom list
Get-PnPList | Where-Object { $_.BaseTemplate -eq 100 } | Format-List
#below is for generic document library
Get-PnPList | Where-Object { $_.BaseTemplate -eq 101 } | Format-List
```

Note: Format-List is to dump property names and values as a list.

Looks simple, but quite tricky to get exactly what you want. You can add on further filters to exclude common library titles such as "Events", "Documents", and ones that are not created by System Account. Read also the [reference for Base Template ID](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/sharepoint_protocols/ms-wssts/8bf797af-288c-4a1d-a14b-cf5394e636cf).

Comment: Thanks, I have done this with BaseTemplate and BaseType already.  the problem is there is no additional properties that can be easily used to filter down,I have compared all the properties using Out-Gridview.  I guess I need to go the other way with this, and try to find a complete list of OOTB list/library names (Style Library, Site Assets, etc) to post filter it

Comment: Yes, it's a little tricky. Even so, each site template will have its own pre-defined OOTB list/library. If it's a new SPO tenant, not so hard to filter. But if it's even an old version of SharePoint on-premises that's sitting years with multiple upgrades, that'd be very unfortunate to filter those out.